# MIPI DSI yocto on Variscite board

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto

I'm really struggling to find any information at all on how to configure MIPI DSI.

The target board is an iMX6 Variscite, running largely unmodified yocto krogoth. We essentially need to switch from LVDS to MIPI (although the screens are also a different resolution).

Assuming that the kernel drivers are present and correct (they appear to be...), what else is there to configure?